# Imprimir en Node.js

Tags: nodejs, impresión

Buena noche, soy nuevo aca, espero no cometer ninguna infraccion y ser de ayuda,les comento que ando liandome con la impresion en Node.js, la necesidad es crear un software en node.js y correrlo directamente en el computador donde tendre conectadas 3 impresoras (las llamaremos a, b y c), de acuerdo al requerimiento va a imprimir en 'a' o en 'b' o en 'c', el problema es que he intentado con un modulo llamado escpos, donde me dice que debo usar un programa de nombre Zadig para imprimir en windows, bueno lo hago asi pero me genera un error que no encuentra la impresora, no se si deba colocar algo en la carpeta del programa o algo asi, el codigo que tengo es:

```
const escpos = require('escpos');

const device  = new escpos.USB();
const printer = new escpos.Printer(device);

device.open(() => {
  printer
    .text('Hello World')
    .feed()
    .cut()
    .close(() => {
      console.log('Close')
    })
});
```

este es el error que genera
[image: Error escpos]
tambien use uno que aconsejaron aca, llamado node-printer, pero tambien me dice que no encuentra la impresora

este es el codigo :

```
var Printer = require('node-printer');
var options = {
    media: 'Custom.200x600mm',
    n: 3
};

// Get available printers list
Printer.list();

// Create a new Pinter from available devices
var printer = new Printer('TM-T88V');

// Print from a buffer, file path or text
var fileBuffer = fs.readFileSync('/path/to/file.ext');
var jobFromBuffer = printer.printBuffer(fileBuffer);

var filePath = 'package.json';
var jobFromFile = printer.printFile(filePath);

var text = 'Print text directly, when needed: e.g. barcode printers'
var jobFromText = printer.printText(text);

// Cancel a job
jobFromFile.cancel();

// Listen events from job
jobFromBuffer.once('sent', function() {
    jobFromBuffer.on('completed', function() {
        console.log('Job ' + jobFromBuffer.identifier + 'has been printed');
        jobFromBuffer.removeAllListeners();
    });
});
```

y este es el error
[image: Error node-printer]

Muchas gracias de antemano por su colaboracion, muchas saludes

Answer (score 7):

Bueno ya lo resolví, coloco la respuesta por si alguien tiene el mismo problema.

Dentro de los parentesis de `USB( )`, al abrir el dispositivo, se debe colocar el `VendorId` y `productId` de la impresora en cuestión, y *voilá*.

```
const escpos = require('escpos');

const device  = new escpos.USB( 0x35b, 0x303 ); // Ejemplo. En MI caso.
const printer = new escpos.Printer(device);
```